# Where can I specify codebuild project properties in aws cdk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am moving to aws cdk from cloudformation and I have below configuration in codebuild project. In CDK, how can I specify these properties like `Triggers`, `BadgeEnabled`?

I am looking at this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-codebuild-readme.html but can't find any fields I can use.

```
CodeBuildProjectDeployment:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    ...
    Properties:
      TimeoutInMinutes: 10
      BadgeEnabled: true
      Triggers:
        !If
          - ShouldAddWebHook
          - Webhook: true
            FilterGroups:
              - - Pattern: PUSH,PULL_REQUEST_CREATED,PULL_REQUEST_UPDATED,PULL_REQUEST_MERGED
                  Type: EVENT
          - !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Triggers` property is specific to `GitHub`. In CDK, you set it up using [GitHubSourceProps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-codebuild.GitHubSourceProps.html):

> Construction properties for {@link GitHubSource} and {@link GitHubEnterpriseSource}.